# Minimal Polynomial Query

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

So I'm having trouble understanding some reasoning of the minimal polynomial theory in Linear Algebra.

To set the scene:

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear map.

We can define $\mu_{Av}$,where A is the corresponding matrix of T, to be the unique monic polynomial p of minimal degree such that

$p(T)(v) = 0_V$

Since $P(T)= 0_V\iff p(T)(v) = 0_V \forall v\in V \iff p(T)(b_i)$ for all basis vectors $b_i$ of V

Now my text is saying that this implies that $\mu_A$,  is the lowest common multiple of the $\mu_{Ab_i}$s, how does this follow? I'm having trouble understanding how this logically flows.

Answer (score 1):

The results from the characterisation of the l.c.m. in a PID $R$: if $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n\in R$, the l.c.m. of $a_1, a_2, \dots $ is a generator of the intersection ideal $\:(a_1)\cap (a_2)\cap\dots\cap(a_n)$.

Comment: Is there a simpler explanation? I've yet to meet ideals.

Comment: I made a very elementary use of ideals. It is possible to detail without using the term, but nevertheless using the concepts, but it will be longer to formulate.